# Cacheing Flask function results across process?

Tags: python, caching, flask, memcached

I have a flask app behind apache that implements basic auth. The username and password are verified against an external service in a boolean function `check_auth`.

I want to cache the username and password if they are correct to reduce load on the external service.

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache

cache = SimpleCache()

def check_auth(username, password):
    if cache.get(username) == password or ext_service_check(username, password):
        cache.set(username, password, 300)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

However Apache always starts multiple processes and this makes me think that if two requests with the same basic auth headers come in, they have a high chance of not hitting the same process and thus not taking advantage of the cache.

At what level does this cache live?

Is `SimpleCache` not going to provide any benefit here?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/contrib/cache/#cache-systems) list several cache systems.  `SimpleCache` is "for single process environments", it won't work across multiple processes.  Right below that is a list of other cache backends; use one appropriate to your environment.  Memcache and Redis are good built-in choices, or you can write your own subclass if you need a different system.